# How to compile and run this C program using Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compilation

Fairly new to Linux and Rasp Pi, I am trying to follow a guide to flash a USB modem. The guide simply says "compile and run this program", which I of course don't know how to do and there are no instructions. I tried researching online but still failed.

This is the utility: https://github.com/forth32/balong-usbdload

It appears to be written in C and has Makefile but that's everything I know.

Can someone explain to me how to compile and run this ? I spent 2 days trying.

I tried "make" and it produced .o files. however I then tried to use the program from within the folder (using the command line) as such:

```
sudo balong-usbdload -p /dev/ttyUSB0 usblsafe-3372h.bin
```

but I got an error saying "no such command..."

How do I run this program ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux requires local executables to be run with relative path notation:

```
sudo ./balong-usbdload -p /dev/ttyUSB0 usblsafe-3372h.bin
```

Running executables without any path notation (e.g. `balong-usbdload`) requires the executable to be located in one of the `$PATH` directories.